# How can I verify client inbound IP address matching with client Domain Name DNS IP address?

Tags: certificate

Typically, server side will verify client certificate common name (CN) matching with client domain name (DN).

But I would need to extend the security checking. I need to verify client inbound IP address matching with client domain name DNS IP address.

For example:-

- Client Server certificate CN & Domain Name as "test.123.net". And "test.123.net" DNS (A) record IP address = 1.1.1.1.
- The connection is https.
- When this client sending a request to my server. firstly, I need to verify the client IP address matching with the DNS IP address. In this case should be the client inbound IP address need use IP address = 1.1.1.1.
- Second, verify certificate CN matching with domain name. In this case which is "test.123.net" matching with the client incoming domain name.

I know I can use OpenSSL or Apache to do the CN and DN verification, but I couldn't find any way to verify the client IP address to matching with the DN DNS IP address.

May I know is there any tool out there in the market can do this? Or can any web server can do this? I tried to google it for a long time but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but this is off topic. I expect you will need to write something as reverse dns is "expensive" from a processing/latency POV and tricky to properly secure. There are also generally better ways of securong thus type of (fairly specific/fragile) method of connecting - eg VPNs

Comment: "Typically"? Honestly I've never heard of _client_ certificates being bound to the IP address the way you describe... ("DN" doesn't mean domain name, it means X.500/LDAP "distinguished name", i.e. the whole set of 'Subject' attributes.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will likely serve you better.

First of all, few organizations own their IP address space, and for them, setting up correct reverse DNS is a hassle involving contacting their ISP and asking for that service. This is often a manual process. This means that in the "typical" case you have no idea what organization is currently using a specific IP address with any tighter granularity than on an ISP level.

This in turn means that if you want to do explicit client certificate lookups, you'll ask the client to create a self-signed certificate and hand you the corresponding CA chain that identifies it as valid from their point of view, or to purchase a certificate from a well-known CA that you can verify independently. In such a case no IP address validation is required, because an eavesdropper who doesn't own the correct private key will only receive an encrypted mess from you - one encrypted with the rightful client's public key.

If you want to increase security beyond this, plan for a VPN tunnel. An alternative (that isn't necessarily good against targeted attacks) would be to limit access to your system to explicit IP addresses.